# How to encode JSON hash using JBuilder in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

There is 'groups' hash, when key of the hash is name of some group, and value of the hash is an array of some items. I want to encode it into JSON, but I can't event encode name of key in hash, because it's not contanstant:

```
x = Jbuilder.encode do |json|
  groups.each do |k, v|     
    json.set!(:group, k)
    json.group k    
  end
end
```

May be you suggest me how to execute method of 'json' using dynamic name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [array! method](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/jbuilder/Jbuilder#array%21-instance_method):

```
json.array!(groups) do |json, group|
    json.set!(group.name, array)
end
```

**Edit:** For a hash of groups with each group's name as its key, do this:

```
groups.each do |group|
    json.set!(group.name, array)
end
```

Comment: Your answer is wrong, I need to render hash of arrays: { "type1": [...], "type2": [...] }. Can you make some example?